Compose Reusable Body and Button, ViewModel, Conditional AlertDialog, Room Database Issue
OK, I feel like I am getting close on this, but I can't quite figure out how to fix it.
Context: working on a database app for a collection.
Presently, I have an AddEntryScreen.kt which has a composable for AddEntryScreen > AddEntryBody. I also have an EditEntryScreen which re-uses the AddEntryBody composable (and passes an updateItem for the save button instead of insertItem).
What I am trying to do is, when entering a new item, clicking save checks the database to see if a unique item already exists (save button isn't even enabled unless the two required fields are filled, and the two required fields in combination are set to be a unique index), and if so, rather than saving, displays an alert dialog asking if you would like to navigate to edit the entry instead... and if the item is unique, doesn't show the altert dialog and inserts then navigates back. I already figured out most of this part, the Dao function works correctly (and tested with database inspector), the confirm button on the dialog works correctly and correctly navigates to the edit screen for that item.
There's 2 issues currently I can't figure out. First the cancel button doesn't work. Secondly, this alert dialog comes up regardless of whether or not the attempted save is unique (though the item will still save if it's unique in spite of the dialog).
At the moment, I have the "navigateBack()" commented-out because it would navigate back and cancel the alert dialog, and I wanted to test the navigate to edit on confirm was working correctly. So, that's also a thing, that even after checking the item for existence, it continues with the rest of the code block (saveItem, navigate back) instead of stopping. I was going to put that in the ViewModel where I could set it in the fuction as if/else, but I couldn't figure out how to get the "navigateBack" to work from there. So, that's also a thing.
I can't seem to figure out what I need to do from here. I need to, I guess somehow move some things to the ViewModel function maybe and somehow make it like, mutable back and forth but, I can't figure out how. It took a lot of playing around to even get the dialog to show when clicking save (I had to add "existState = viewModel.existState" to the EntryScreen composable to pass it down to the body. I'm kind of understanding a little of what I am doing, but it's so much back-and-forth between the Screen and Body composables and the ViewModel that my head is spinning and I'm getting dizzy.
So, here's the relevant code from each part (I can provide more if need be):
AddEntryScreen.kt
@Composable
fun AddEntryScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
    navigateToEditEntry: (Int) -> Unit,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = true,
    viewModel: AddEntryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
){
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var existCheck by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
        {...}
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        AddEntryBody(
            itemUiState = viewModel.itemUiState,
            existState = viewModel.existState,
            onItemValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            onSaveClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.checkItemExistsOnSave()
                        if (ExistState().exists) {
                            existCheck = ExistState().existCheck
                        }
                        else {
                            delay(500.milliseconds)
                            viewModel.saveItem()
//                            navigateBack()
                        }

               }
            },

            onDeleteClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.deleteItem()
                    navigateBack()
                }
            },
            isEditEntry = false,
            navigateToEditEntry = navigateToEditEntry,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize(),
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun AddEntryBody(
    itemUiState: ItemUiState,
    existState: ExistState,
    onItemValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit,
    navigateToEditEntry: (Int) -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: () -> Unit,
    onDeleteClick: () -> Unit,
    isEditEntry: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var deleteConfirm by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
        ItemInputForm(
            itemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails,
            onValueChange = onItemValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
         Button(
             onClick = { onSaveClick() },
             enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
             shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
             modifier = Modifier
                 .fillMaxWidth()
                 .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
         ) {
             Text(text = stringResource(R.string.save))
         }
        if (existState.existCheck) {
            ItemExistsDialog(
                onItemExistsConfirm = {
                    existState.existCheck = false
                    navigateToEditEntry(existState.transferId)
                },
                onItemExistsCancel = { existState.existCheck = false },
            )
        }

        if (isEditEntry) {
            Button(
                onClick = { deleteConfirm = true },
                enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
                colors = ButtonColors(
                    containerColor = Color(0xFF990000),
                    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onError,
                    disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
                    disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.delete_forever), contentDescription = null)
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.delete))
            }
            if (deleteConfirm) {
                DeleteConfirmationDialog(
                    onDeleteConfirm = {
                        deleteConfirm = false
                        onDeleteClick()
                    },
                    onDeleteCancel = { deleteConfirm = false },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(0.dp)
                )
            }
        } else {
           // do nothing //
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemExistsDialog(
    onItemExistsConfirm: () -> Unit,
    onItemExistsCancel: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { /* Do nothing */ },
        title = { Text(stringResource(R.string.attention)) },
        text = { Text(stringResource(R.string.item_exists)) },
        modifier = modifier,
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onItemExistsCancel) {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.cancel))
            }
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onItemExistsConfirm) {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.yes))
            }
        }
    )
}

AddEntryViewModel
class AddEntryViewModel(
    private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository
): ViewModel() {

    /** current item state **/
    var itemUiState by mutableStateOf(ItemUiState())
        private set

    /** update item state **/
    fun updateUiState(itemDetails: ItemDetails) {
        itemUiState =
            ItemUiState(
                itemDetails = itemDetails,
                isEntryValid = validateInput(itemDetails),
            )
    }

    private fun validateInput(uiState: ItemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails): Boolean {
        return with(uiState) {
            brand.isNotBlank() && blend.isNotBlank()
        }
    }

    /** check if Item already exists, display optional dialog if so **/
    var existState by mutableStateOf(ExistState())

    suspend fun checkItemExistsOnSave() {
        val currentItem = itemUiState.itemDetails
        if (itemsRepository.exists(currentItem.brand, currentItem.blend)) {
            existState =
                ExistState(
                    exists = true,
                    transferId = itemsRepository.getItemIdByIndex(
                        currentItem.brand, currentItem.blend
                    ),
                    existCheck = true
                )
        }
//        else {
//            existState =
//                ExistState(
//                    exists = false,
//                    transferId = 0,
//                    existCheck = false,
//                )
//        }
    }

    /** save to or delete from database **/
    suspend fun saveItem() {
        if (validateInput()) {
            itemsRepository.insertItem(itemUiState.itemDetails.toItem())
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteItem() {
        if (validateInput()) {
            itemsRepository.deleteItem(itemUiState.itemDetails.toItem())
        }
    }
}

data class ExistState(
    val exists: Boolean = false,
    val transferId: Int = 0,
    var existCheck: Boolean = false,
)

data class ItemUiState(
    val itemDetails: ItemDetails = ItemDetails(),
    val isEntryValid: Boolean = false,
)

data class ItemDetails(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val brand: String = "",
    val blend: String = "",
    val type: String = "",
    val quantity: Int = 1,
    val hated: Boolean = false,
    val favorite: Boolean = false,

And if anyone was curious about the database exist check and Id pull thing to navigate to the item edit and pass in the existing item data:
**Dao:**
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand = :brand AND blend = :blend)")
suspend fun exists(brand: String, blend: String): Boolean

@Query("SELECT id FROM items WHERE brand = :brand AND blend = :blend")
suspend fun getItemIdByIndex(brand: String, blend: String): Int

**Items Repository:**
suspend fun exists(brand: String, blend: String): Boolean

suspend fun getItemIdByIndex(brand: String, blend: String): Int

**Offline Items Repository:**
override suspend fun exists(brand: String, blend: String): Boolean {
    return itemsDao.exists(brand, blend) != null
}

override suspend fun getItemIdByIndex(brand: String, blend: String) = itemsDao.getItemIdByIndex(brand, blend)


EDIT/UPDATE:
I've now gotten the "cancel" button on the ItemExists dialog to work. I created a function in the ViewModel..
fun resetExistState() {
    existState =
        ExistState(
            exists = false,
            transferId = 0,
            existCheck = false,
        )
}

And added "resetExistState: () -> Unit," as a parameter of AddEntryBody.
While this works, I feel like maybe this is the wrong approach. And since the AddEntryBody is used in the EditEntryScreen as well, I've had to add empty lambda "navigateToEditEntry = {}," and "resetExistState = {}," stuff that isn't used in EditEntryScreen when calling the AddEntryBody to the scaffold. It doesn't break anything there, but it does mean every edit of the AddEntryScreen in this way to get this to work means EditEntryScreen also has to be changed, which starts to defeat the purpose because I'm adding elements that aren't reusable.
I did also solve the issue of the existCheck dialog popping up even when the answer is false. One potential clue to this issue is in my OfflineItemsRepository, the override function for the check says it always returns true, so I was looking at it and saw "!= null", I erased that and that fixed that issue. Not sure why I had that there.
Now I just need to get the "navigateBack" to work when saving an item that doesn't exist, an not trigger when an item does exist.

FINAL EDIT/UPDATE:
I finally got it all working how it is I want it to work... now my question is... is this janky/hacky or there a better way to do it? Full current [relevant] code below.
Some of the changes include how I call things, because I really don't know what I am doing. So instead of declaring variables and calling stuff, I call viewModel.existState instead of ExistState() for instance. That was half my problem, calling the right thing in the right place, hoisting the right things to the right places, etc.
Bear in mind, the composable AddEntryBody here is re-used in the EditEntryScreen... and when called over there, empty lambda's are used for the "navigateToEditEntry" and "resetExistState" parameters and existState is set = ExistState() (even though none of those three things are used on the EditEntryScreen).
AddEntryScreen:
@Composable
fun AddEntryScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
    navigateToEditEntry: (Int) -> Unit,
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = true,
    viewModel: AddEntryViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
){
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
    {...}
    ) { innerPadding ->
    AddEntryBody(
            itemUiState = viewModel.itemUiState,
            existState = viewModel.existState,
            onItemValueChange = viewModel::updateUiState,
            onSaveClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    delay(125.milliseconds)
                    viewModel.checkItemExistsOnSave()
                    delay(125.milliseconds)
                    if (!viewModel.existState.exists) {
                        viewModel.saveItem()
                        navigateBack()
                    }
                }
            },
            onDeleteClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    viewModel.deleteItem()
                    navigateBack()
                }
            },
            isEditEntry = false,
            navigateToEditEntry = navigateToEditEntry,
            resetExistState = viewModel::resetExistState,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize(),
        )
    }
}

fun AddEntryBody(
    itemUiState: ItemUiState,
    existState: ExistState,
    onItemValueChange: (ItemDetails) -> Unit,
    navigateToEditEntry: (Int) -> Unit,
    resetExistState: () -> Unit,
    onSaveClick: () -> Unit,
    onDeleteClick: () -> Unit,
    isEditEntry: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    innerPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp)
) {
    var deleteConfirm by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
        ItemInputForm(
            itemDetails = itemUiState.itemDetails,
            onValueChange = onItemValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
         Button(
             onClick = { onSaveClick() },
             enabled = itemUiState.isEntryValid,
             shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
             modifier = Modifier
                 .fillMaxWidth()
                 .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
         ) {
             Text(text = stringResource(R.string.save))
         }
        if (existState.existCheck) {
            ItemExistsDialog(
                onItemExistsConfirm = {
                    resetExistState()
                    navigateToEditEntry(existState.transferId)
                },
                onItemExistsCancel = { resetExistState() },
            )
        }

        if (isEditEntry) {...

AddEntryViewModel:
    /** check if Item already exists, display optional dialog if so **/
    var existState by mutableStateOf(ExistState())

    suspend fun checkItemExistsOnSave() {
        val currentItem = itemUiState.itemDetails
        if (itemsRepository.exists(currentItem.brand, currentItem.blend)) {
            existState =
                ExistState(
                    exists = true,
                    transferId = itemsRepository.getItemIdByIndex(
                        currentItem.brand, currentItem.blend),
                    existCheck = true
                )
        }
        else if (!itemsRepository.exists(currentItem.brand, currentItem.blend)) {
            existState =
                ExistState(
                    exists = false,
                    transferId = 0,
                    existCheck = false,
                )
//            saveItem()
        }
    }

    fun resetExistState() {
        existState =
            ExistState(
                exists = false,
                transferId = 0,
                existCheck = false,
            )
    }


I'm assuming I need to un-comment/enable the else block of the ViewModel function "checkItemExistsOnSave" and call the save function in that else block. I swear I tried that before though and it didn't work, but I have been modifying this code so much hack and forth, maybe I need to try again as it is now.
